# OOM error when training TensorFlow object-detection API using inception-resnet & NASnet (especially) as backbone

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

Please help me finding the solution to my problems. It's important for me to state first that, I have successfully created my own custom dataset and I have successfully trained that dataset using resnet101 on my own computer (16GB RAM and 4GB NVIDIA 980).

The problem arise when I tried to switch the backbone using inception-resnet and nasnet. I got the following error

```
"ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape ..."
```

And I thought I didn't have enough resource on my computer, so I created instance on AWS EC2 with 60GB RAM and 12GB NVIDIA Tesla K80 (my work place only provide this service) and trained the network there.

The training for inception-resnet worked well, however that's not the case with nasnet. Even with 100GB memory I still get OOM error

I found one solution on github tensorflow models web page at [issue #1817](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1817)  and I followed the instruction by adding the following line of code into nasnet config file

```
train_config: {
  batch_size: 1
  batch_queue_capacity: 50
  num_batch_queue_threads: 8
  prefetch_queue_capacity: 10
...
```

and the code ran well for a while ([the following is "top" screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KG0oX.png)). However, I still got the OOM error after running around 6000 steps

```
INFO:tensorflow:global step 6348: loss = 2.0393 (3.988 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoint to path /home/ubuntu/crack-detection/structure-crack/models/faster_rcnn_nas_coco_2017_11_08/train/model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:global step 6349: loss = 0.9803 (3.980 sec/step)
2018-01-25 05:51:25.959402: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:273] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 79.73MiB.  Current allocation summary follows.
...

ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[64,17,17,4032]
     [[Node: MaxPool2D/MaxPool = MaxPool[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", ksize=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], 
...
```

Is there anything else I could do to run this smoothly without any OOM errors? Thanks for your help

---

**EDIT #1**: The errors come more frequently now, it'll show after 1000-1500 steps.

**EDIT #2**: Based on the [issue #2668](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2668) and [issue #3014](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3014), there's one more thing we can do to be able to run the code without OOM error by adding `second_stage_batch_size: 25` (default is 50) in model section of the config file. So, the file should look like the following

```
model{
  faster_rcnn {
    ...
    second_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    second_stage_classification_loss_weight: 1.0
    second_stage_batch_size: 25
  }
}
```

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out that the memory that you run out of is the one of the GPU, so I'm afraid those 100GB are only useful for data wrangling outside a training purpose. Also, without code, it's really difficult to figure out where the error is coming from.

That being said, if you can initialize the neural net architecture with weights, train for 6000 iterations and suddenly run out of GPU memory then I guess that you are either somehow storing values in GPU memory or, if you have variable length inputs, you might be passing a sequence, in that iteration, which is too big memory wise.

Comment: Hi @Diego, thanks for the reply. Does it mean I have to increase the GPU memory in order to train NASnet smoothly?

Comment: That would be the easy, brute force, expensive way to do it. Like I said... it's weird that it does train and suddenly runs out of memory.

There are tricks you could try to implement to reduce the memory usage, for example trim the NASnet weights see this resource: https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/quantization.

My advice would be to try to find work arounds in the training procedure first.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. However, I don't know what else I could do to train nasnet smoothly (I may have to look at the quantization method that you mention). The issue #1817 that I put on the post gave me an impression that the OOM errors come from RAM and not GPU memory.

Comment: I highly doubt its a RAM memory issue, but just in case get the size of the backbone weights. That should give you an idea of where to start debugging.

Comment: take a look here at how to count the total number of params in your architecture: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-count-the-total-number-of-parameters-in-a-model-in-TensorFlow.

Then consider the correct size: float32 or float64 to estimate it's size.